# Submit Form | Confirm Save Changes Validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a form where by a user is presented with a "Save Changes" button first, if the user clicks this button and there are no validation issues the user will be presented with a "Confirm Changes" button.

My code to achieve this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                        <span ng-hide="confirm">
                            <button type="button" class="vfnz-submit" ng-click="confirm = ! confirm;">Save changes</button>
                            <a ng-href="#/huntgroups/" class="vfnz-reset">Cancel</a>
                        </span>
                        <div class="hide" ng-class="{ 'hide': ! confirm }">
                            <button type="submit" class="vfnz-submit confirm-changes">Confirm changes</button>
                            <a class="vfnz-reset" ng-click="confirm = ! confirm;">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is working well however, If there are any errors within the form I want the errors to show on "Save Changes". The logic I have to ensure validation shows on submit is like so:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(form, isValid){
                if (!isValid){
                  $scope.submitted = true;
                } else {
                  $scope.submitted = false;
                }
    }
```

I'm unsure what to change or how to achieve the changes I'm after.

Just to reiterate:

On save changes, show error messages if any. If there are error messages, don't show confirm changes. If there are no error messages, show confirm changes and then submit.

Answer (score 1):

you want something like this.... tweak it... 
I have a better example but its on my work laptop ... can give it to you tomorrow :) 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANxmv/1480/)

```
    <form name="form" no-validate ng-app>
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Your email address</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks dude - I'll take this and see what I can do. If I get a working solution I will post it!

Comment: sure... this is the kind of solution you want... I just see the rend on focus... it cant be fixed... didnt dwell on it for too long. Im sure from here you'll be able to get what you want